How to fix - forest not responding after more data ingested in marklogic?
I was trying to update huge set of data and did not realise the space left for the forest. Now the forest is in bad state and throwing XDMP-FORESTERR. How to fix this issue as that database is not accessible now.
I was trying to delete some data but as database is not responding I can not do anything using QC.

You have run out of disk space and your drive is full? Have you killed the process that was inserting docs, to stop making things worse?
As you load content, MarkLogic will attempt to merge and consolidate stands. If you don't have enough free disk space to hold the current stands and the new stand (which can be as large as the merge max size), then it will start reporting errors for the merges (XDMP-MERGESPACE) and warn about disk capacity. Eventually, you may encounter other errors, such as SVC-FILWRT that impact other operations and can prevent the system from operating.
There are a few procedures for recovering from low disk space outlined in this knowledgebase article:
https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/49/16/recovering-from-low-disk-space
You might also consider opening a MarkLogic Support Ticket in order to get some guidance and assistance for your specific situation.
